# SAS: Calculating average (Euclidean) distance from each customer to all other customers in table

Tags: sas, distance, euclidean-distance

I have a SAS dataset of 60k customers with the following attributes:
1) customer number
2) X coordinate
3) Y coordinate
4) store visits

I need to calculate the average weighted distance from each customer to all the other customers in the table where each distance is weighted by the comparing customer's number of visits.  As an example, the distance between Customer A & Customer B is 10.  We would then weight that distance by Customer B's number of visits (2) which equals 5.  This process would repeat for all other customers in the table and we would then average all of these weighted distances for each of the 60k customers.

I suppose the brute force way to do this is a Cartesian join (ie. create a 60k x 60k = 3.6 billion record table) but that will likely run out of memory or crash SAS.  I have also thought of breaking this up into more manageable Cartesian joins (ie. 10 x 60K = 600k x 6000 iterations but this is likely to be quite time consuming -- maybe my only choice though).  I'm guessing you guys/gals know a much better way to do this!

I appreciate all your suggestions.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: This sounds like a design issue: why is the project designed this way?  Perhaps consider a better design that doesn't require this sort of computation?  If you're doing some sort of cluster analysis, you should consider using SAS procedures that do this for you.

Comment: @Joe, I agree that if this is some cluster analysis, it would be better done in a procedure, using a less intensive procedure.  However, there is no procedure that I am aware of that calculates linkage like this between all points.  If the author is looking for a number to represent likeness of the group, weighted average distance from the mean might be a better choice and much easier to calculate.

Comment: @Joe, the project is to calculate a customer catchment around a store.  We have geo-located 60k customers and calculated their 52 week visit behavior.  The idea is to create a score, for each customer, that explains the types of customers around him/her.  The main idea here is that if Customer A lives close to other customers that visit the store frequently then its likely that Customer A lives in the catchment area of the store.  Conversely, if Customer Z lives close to other customers that barely visit the store then its likely he/she does not live in the catchment.

Answer (score 2):

Bad news, there is no way to speed up this calculation (that I know of).

Good news is SAS won't crash or run out of memory if you do a Cartesian product.  Other good news is doing this in a data step is faster than doing it in PROC SQL.

```
data test;
do cn=1 to 64000;
    x = ceil(Ranuni(13)*100);
    y = ceil(ranuni(13)*100);
    visits = max(1,round(rannor(12)*3 + 8,1));
    output;
end;
run;

sasfile test load;

data ave_dist(keep=cn ave_dist);
set test end=last;

dist=0;
td= 0;
total_visits=0;
do i=1 to n;
    set test(rename=(cn=cn_2 x=x_2 y=y_2) drop=visits) point=i nobs=n;

    if cn ^= cn_2 then do;
        xx = (x-x_2);
        yy = (y-y_2);
        total_visits = total_visits + visits;
            dist = sqrt(xx*xx + yy*yy);
        if dist^= 0 then
            dist = 1/dist;
    else 
        dist = 100; /*Adjust to something that makes sense to your data*/
        td = visits*dist + td;
    end;
end;

ave_dist = td / total_visits;   
output;

run;

sasfile test close;
```

I inverted the distance calculation.  You want small distances to have a higher score.  I made this a true visit weighted average.

This takes about 13 minutes to run on my laptop.

Comment: @DomPass, Thank you very much for looking into this.  It is good to hear that the Cartesion join will not cause the crippling problems I suspected.  The above code (Using the data statement) calculates just one average over all customers but I would need an average for each customer instead (ie. the average distance to all other customers).  More over, the weighting I planned to use will not work.  What I am trying to do is give a customer a high score if they live next to customers that have many visits and low scores for living next to customers who have few visits.  Any ideas?

Comment: @AdamL, sure, instead of the `if last then do` statement, just calculate the average and `output;`.  I will update the code and explanation to achieve what I think you are looking for.

Comment: @DomPazz, sorry, I can't find where you calculated the euclidean distance?

Comment: @user102890, you are correct.  It got hosed in my edit.  Fixing now.

Answer (score 1):

if your customers base is going to be <100k then `PROC DISTANCE` could be of help. Using the dataset created by @DomPazz you could run the following code and examine the results. In this case I'm only trying it out on the first 10K customers which runs in 16secs. Do not let that fool you into false sense of security. When you double the no. of customers the time taken goes by 4times.
(actual times: 10K - 16secs, 20K - 47 secs, 40K - 3mins...)

This procedure produce a `NxN` square matrix (where N is the no. of customers in your input dataset). You could try and experiment and see at what point SAS runs into `RAM` memory issues ( be sure to have plenty of hard drive space, at least in the order of 1.10*NxN*8bytes).
Each cell in the matrix represents `i`th customer's (in rows) distance with 'j'th customer (in columns). Once you get the distance it is a simple matter of multiplying the respective distances with the customer's visits and taking the average.

```
proc distance data = test(obs = 100)
OUT=test_distances(compress = binary)
METHOD= EUCLID shape = SQUARE 
UNDEF=1000000
VARDEF=wdf;
var INTERVAL(x y)
;
copy cn visits;
run;

data avg_dist;
set train_distances;
array dist{*} dist:;
prod=0;
do i = 1 to dim(dist);
prod = visits*dist{i}+prod;
end;

avg_dist=prod/dim(dist);

dims=dim(dist);

drop i dist:
;
run;
proc sql;
drop table test_distances;
quit;
```

The type of problem you are looking to solve are generally known as `k-nearest neighbour` problems. There has been decades of research in this area and most often these are solved using special data-structures such as `Kd-trees` for performance. Most often one is interested in answering questions such as `who are the top-10 (or K) closest customers to this customer I'm interested in?` Another procedure which is very good for solving these type of problems efficiently is the `PROC PMBR` which supports both `kd-tree` and SAS's proprietary structure called the `Rd-tree` - look it up - you will only find a pdf document from SAS Eminer 4.3 days

The moment you are having to calculate distance between N*N items you are asking for trouble.
From reading your project description in the comments it appears that what you need is not calculate distance between every customer with every other customer but something like distance between every customer and every store.

This will dramatically improve your query performance since the dimensionality of the problem is greatly reduced.

Let's say you have N customers and S stores then you only need to calculate distance between N*S points. ( a simple data step will do the job as there is no need for a cartesian product nor specialised data structures)

From there you can look at, for each store in S what proportion of the customer's who shoped at that store live with in 1KM, 2KM, 3KM ....

Then you can come up answers such as 80% live within 1km , 15% live within 2KM etc...

Comment: @uer102890, the reason I want to calculate to each customer is because I need their behavior to determine the catchment.  Yes, I could easily calculate their distance to the store.  But that means I am the one creating an arbitrary catchment cutoff.  But if I find that a pocket of customers happens to visit each week out of the last 52 then I can safely assume this group of customers (and those that live close) are in the catchment.  Essentially, I want the customers to show me they are in the catchment, not the other way around.